# How many numbers lying between 10 and 100 can be formed with the help of digits 1,3,5,7,9?

Tags: permutations

Please help me!! i don't know how resolve this problem.
This is exercise from permutations in my school. hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: At worst you could write down a list of all the numbers and count it by hand. If you have a particular question about how to approach this in a non-bruteforce approach, please be more explicit and explain what you tried already.

Answer (score 3):

all permutations with repetitions of order 2 from set $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$are
$$11,13,31,33,15,51,55,17,71,77,19,91,99$$
$$35,53,37,73,39,93$$
$$57,75,59,95$$
$$79,97$$

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct all 2-digit number by $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ 
so for first digit you have $5$ number, that can select, and for the second too.

Answer (score 1):

Any number between $10,100$ is a two digit number.

What is the number of ordered pairs that are made up using elements in the set $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

nPr will give you the answer => correct me if i am wrong, I learned probability some 7 years back :)

here n= 5 {1,3,5,7,9} and r= 2

Correction : nPr + n Will be the answer

Comment: ${}_nC_r$ counts the number of combinations, which are unordered sets of *distinct* elements.  Thus, you would miss $11$, $33$, etc.

Comment: This does not count $33$

Comment: i edited the answer, it is nPr

Comment: answer for it will be 20

Comment: oooppppps.. yeah still i will miss 11,33, 55... :(

Comment: please correct your answer

Comment: Please correct your answer, or delete it. There's no shame in deleting an answer (I've done so, quite a few times.

Comment: corrected the answer :D